# Rails 7, How to delete image uploaded on Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary, rails-activestorage

I have Rails 7. I've set up Active Storage with Cloudinary. When I write an article with one or more images, the image is correctly uploaded to Cloudinary. However, when I delete the article, it doesn't remove the images from Cloudinary. I've installed the gem 'activestorage-cloudinary-service' and modified my model accordingly, but it hasn't made any difference. Is there another way to do it?

My model :

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true
  has_many_attached :images, service: :cloudinary, dependent: :purge
  has_many :article_categories, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :article_categories
end
```

config/storage.yml :

```
test:
service: Disk
 root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

 # local:
 #   service: Disk
 #   root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

 cloudinary:
    service: Cloudinary
    cloud_name: myname
    api_key: _______
    api_secret: ____
    environment: <%= ENV['CLOUDINARY_URL'] %>
    secure: true
    prefix: development/
```

I have installed the gem 'activestorage-cloudinary-service', i have modified the model.
I have test in console, it doesn't delete on Cloudinary.
Exept, when i upload an image in rails c.
I have see, that when i do in console, it puts the image in a folder named "development", and when i do in my form, he puts the image out of the folder.
It's probably for this reason, he can't delete the image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem might be related to the folder structure where the images are being uploaded. The distinction between placing images in the "development" folder when uploaded via the console and placing them outside the folder when uploaded through your form. Please try changing that and see if that's the issue.

Comment: Finally, the distinction didn't change anything. I have test, it.
I remove the folder on Cloudinary, and it didn't change anything. I can't remove an image, and i can't update an image on Cloudinary.
If you have an idea...

Comment: For informations, i progress in the problem. I saw, that it was the integration of TinyMCE.
In fact, i use TinyMCE and Cloudinary. And when i upload an image in TinyMCE, it's OK. But i can do just this.
I would like to be able to update and delete image in tinyMCE, when i update or delete an article.